# How can I replace the certbot ssl certicate with a commercial ssl certifcate?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, certbot

I enabled https on my nodejs application hosted on digital ocean. I used certbot. I want to replace the free certificate with a commercial certificate so not it shows up as "secure". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site does not show **secure** with a free certificate, there is a problem with your configuration. Buying one will not fix that problem unless the issue is an expired certificate.

To change certificates copy the private key and certificate to a safe location on your server  and then change the Apache VirtualHost configuration:

- SSLCertificateFile /fullpath/to/fullchain.pem
- SSLCertificateKeyFile /fullpath/to/privkey.pem

Of course, replace **/fullpath/to/** to the directory you created to store your certificate.

Example: **/etc/certs/example.com**

The file names depends on the names your CA sent you. Use their filenames or rename them as you wish.